# Cannot able to add groups to my azure active directory from graph explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add group to my Azure Active Directory from Graph Explorer with URL 

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` and JSON body

```
{
  "description": "Group with designated owner and members",
  "displayName": "Operations group",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "operations2019",
  "securityEnabled": true,
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user object id}"
  ],
  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user object id}"
  ]
}
```

but throwing error message as below

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "Method not allowed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ba759d0f-3585-4d65-b1e1-204de53186ad",
            "date": "2019-11-19T13:37:46"
        }
    }
}
```

But I can get a successful response for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Please, help me.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the logs (thanks for providing a request id and timestamp!) and it looks like the request was for a consumer account (like outlook.com or live.com) instead of an organization account.

According to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http POST /groups isn't supported with MSA.

If you have a work/school account can you sign into Graph explorer with that account?

Comment: I am having my organization account. But I am using azure free trail which is created with outlook.com account. I cannot use my organization account. Can I create groups using powershell or c# ??